# HTML Validation issues CSS parse error, How do I fix?

Tags: html

I'm currently making a website and I'm currently validating it. I have an issue on one of my pages where it say CSS Parse Error but I don't know where I've gone wrong

I have put my code into a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qtjd0Xpq); It says it's originating from line 52. more specifically the last line (empty) here;

```
  body {
  font-family: "Arial, sans-serif"; 
  box-sizing: "border-box";}
```

Could anyone potentially help me?
Thanks,
Benji.

Comment: That code isn't responsible for the error. Look at the context. You've got a chunk of HTML immediately before it.

Comment: Why are using  `"border-box"`, take away `"`

Comment: And use font family as `font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You appear to have this partway through your CSS:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is not valid CSS and so cannot be parsed and should be put outside of the `<style>` tags.

Not only this, you appear to be redefining your `body` style after the HTML which suggests to me that you have copied some code into your project incorrectly.

As others have also mentioned, the usage of quotes around `border-box` is not necessary. If you like more information on the parsing of CSS, look here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/